# jquery mobile flashes previous page after transition

Tags: jquery-mobile, rhodes, rhomobile

Have page have list with link to show item.

when I click back to list item from show page, it goes back to list, flashes show page and comes back to list.

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" class="nearbyList">
      <% @places.each do |place| %>

          <li>
            <a href="<%= url_for :action => :show, :id => place.object %>">
              <%= place.name %><br />
            </a>
          </li>

      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

then link back on show:

```
<a href="<%= @back %>" class="ui-btn-left" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This was only true on my Android phone. Using Chrome on my PC did not have this glitch.

The only solution I found was to use a pop up transition, or not to use transitions at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm answering your question, but I've tried to set
"hashListeningEnabled" to false and the page doesn't flash back.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.extend($.mobile, {
        hashListeningEnabled: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't that break navigation in multi-pages where you use the hash for the link?